# 2次元の零行列に数値を代入していく時のコードに関して

Tags: python, python3

AOJの[ITP1_7_C問題](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/description.jsp?id=ITP1_7_C&lang=ja)からのものです
H行W列の行列が与えられ、その行ごとの和と列ごとの和をH+1行、W+1行目に追加した後に
出力するコードを書くのが目標です。((H+1,W+1)の場所には全要素の総和を出力)

pythonのH+1行W+1列の2次元リスト(行列)を0で埋めた後(indexできるように)、標準入力の行列(H,W)を読み込んでいくのですが、

```
H,W = map(int,input().split())

table = [[0]*(W+1) for i in range(H+1)]

for row in range(H):
    work = list(map(int,input().split())) #★★直にtableに代入すると、列数が変わってしまう!!!★★★
    for col in range(W):
        table[row][col] = work[col]
```

ここで上記のコメントにあるように

```
work = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

を除いた場合に何故、列数が変わってしまうのか分かりません。

解説していただける方いらっしゃいましたら、よろしくお願い致します。

参考程度に解答例のコード全体も以下に載せておきます。

```
H,W = map(int,input().split())

table = [[0]*(W+1) for i in range(H+1)]

for row in range(H):
    work = list(map(int,input().split())) #★★直にtableに代入すると、列数が変わってしまう!!!★★★
    for col in range(W):
        table[row][col] = work[col]


for row in range(H):
    for col in range(0,W):
        table[row][W] += table[row][col]


for col in range(0,W+1):
    for row in range(0,H):
        table[H][col] += table[row][col]


for row in range(0,H+1):
    print("%d"%(table[row][0]),end="")
    for col in range(1,W+1):
        print(" %d"%(table[row][col]),end = "")
    print()
```

Comment: `table = [[0]*(W+1) for i in range(H+1)]` の部分ですが、`(W, H)` ではなく `(W+1, H+1)` サイズにしているのは何か理由があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 申し訳ありません、文脈が不足していました。質問を編集させて頂きましたので再度よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「直にtableに代入する」というのは `for row in range(H): table[row] = list(map(int,input().split()))` という事でしょうか？ その場合、`table[row]` の内容が「入れ替え」られてしまいます(実際には table の要素(リスト型インスタンス)へのポインタが付け替えられてしまいます)。リストの内容を部分的に変更する場合は slicing を使うとよろしいかと思います。`for row in range(H): table[row][:W] = list(map(int,input().split()))`

Comment: metropolisさんがおっしゃっているslicingによる部分的な変更と、```for row in range(H): table[row] = list(map(int,input().split()))```による「入れ替え」の違いを教えていただけると幸いです。また、それとは別ですが解答例のコメントアウトの「直にtableに代入すると列数が変わってしまう」は入れ替え云々と別の何か不具合が発生してしまう、という意味なのだと解釈しているのですが、列数が変わってしまう原因を教えていただけますと光栄です。

Comment: [Visualize Python, Java, JavaScript, C, C++, Ruby code execution](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html) で実行の様子を可視化したものを見ると分かりやすいかもしれません。[table の初期化直後](https://pasteboard.co/J1iK0u3.png)、[table\[row\] = list(map(int,input().split())) の場合](https://pasteboard.co/J1iKo8D.png)、[table\[row\]\[:W\] = list(map(int,input().split())) の場合](https://pasteboard.co/J1iL4yB.png) です。違いが分かりますでしょうか？

Comment: 実行の様子を可視化できるサイトがある事を初めて知りました。ありがとうございます。問題の「入れ替え」の原因(機序？)なのですが、table[0] = list(略)と実行された時に、tableというlistの一部分(これはtable[0]は見たところ0行目の要素全体を指定しているように見えるのですが)に、要素ではなく新たにlistができてしまっている、という事でしょうか？　説明するのは難しいかもしれませんが、「 table の要素(リスト型インスタンス)へのポインタが付け替えられてしまいます」の部分を詳しく解説していただけると幸いです。

Comment: 既に回答の承認が行われていますので手短に言いますと、`table` の中身はポインタの配列になっています(先の画像の通り)。`list(map(int,input().split()))` が実行された時点で新たにリストが作成されていて、このリストの先頭アドレスへのポインタが `table[0]` に格納されることになります。また、元のリスト`[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` は消えたわけではなく、後で garbage collection で回収される事になります。的確な説明ができなくてすみませんが、以上です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

リンク先の出題にあるSample Inputを元にして説明します。

#### Sample Input

```
4 5
1 1 3 4 5
2 2 2 4 5
3 3 0 1 1
2 3 4 4 6
```

1行目の`4 5`を`H, W`に読み込んだ後に

```
table = [[0]*(W+1) for i in range(H+1)]
```

を実行すると、`table`の中身は次のようにネストしたリスト(いわゆる二次元配列)になります。

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #← 各列の合計を書き込む行
] #              ↑各行の合計を書き込むための列
```

出題の指定通りに各列の合計のための行、各行の合計のための列が付け足された(4+1)行(5+1)列の二次元配列が作られます。

さて、「直にtableに代入する」と言うのは、こう言うことを言っているのだと思われます。

```
for row in range(H):
    table[row] = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

最初の1行分`1 1 3 4 5`を読み込むと`list(map(int,input().split()))`の値は`[1, 1, 3, 4, 5]`と言う5要素のリストになるわけですから、途中結果は以下のようになります。

```
[[1, 1, 3, 4, 5],   #←この行が`table[0]`だから、`table[0]`が`[1, 1, 3, 4, 5]`に置き換えられる
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #← 各列の合計を書き込む行
] #              ↑各行の合計を書き込むための列
```

ご覧のように1行目からは、行の合計を保持するための6番目の要素がなくなってしまいます。

4行分全部実行完了すると、こんな感じですね。

```
[[1, 1, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 2, 2, 4, 5],
 [3, 3, 0, 1, 1],
 [2, 3, 4, 4, 6],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #← 各列の合計を書き込む行
] #              ↑各行の合計を書き込むための列
```

ご覧のように1〜4行目については、「列数が変わってしまう」と言うことになります。

---

先に「いわゆる二次元配列」と言う書き方をしましたが、Pythonの場合、リストのリストであり、外側のリストの各要素が全部同じ長さのリストになるようにして、擬似的に「二次元配列」として使っているだけに過ぎません。

外側のリストの各要素を書き換えて、別の長さのリストにしてしまうことができる(なんならリスト以外のものに書き換えることもできる)と言うことがわかれば、「列数が変わってしまう」と言う挙動も理解できるのではないかと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか?